# Паттерн "наблюдатель" в приложении клиент-сервер

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, клиент-сервер

Пишу на Java. Необходимо создать клиент-серверное приложение, с поддержкой нескольких клиентов. Хотелось бы реализовать это используя паттерн наблюдатель. Сервер запускается отдельно, клиент отдельно. Необходимо передать клиенту в параметре запущенный сервер. Если вы что-нибудь поняли, то ответьте мне. Просто хочу, чтобы рассылка клиентам сообщений от сервера был такая же, как в паттерне "наблюдатель".

```
для полного прикола добавлю код

public class Client implements Observer {
private String result = "";
private Subject server;

public Client(Subject server){

    this.server = server;
    server.registerObserver(this);
}

@Override
public void update(String result) {
    this.result = result;       
}

static void connectionToServer(){
    try {
        Socket fromServer = new Socket("localhost",8189);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fromServer.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fromServer.getOutputStream(),true);
        BufferedReader inu = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String fUser;
        String fServer;

        while((fUser = inu.readLine()) != null){
            out.println(fUser);
            fServer = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(fServer);
            if (fUser.equals("close")) break;
        }
        fromServer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    connectionToServer();
}
```

}

на коннекшн не смотрите. Как мне в мейне создать клиент? передать ему в параметре сервер? не могу я в рамках этого мейна создать сервер, так как он уже запущен.

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема? Если не ясен шаблон - в той-же вики отличный пример, в т.ч. на ява. Если не совсем ясна суть, то начните писать, как появится более конкретный вопрос - спросите и вам помогут.

Просто фраза "Если вы что-нибудь поняли, то ответьте мне", как я понял, намекает на то, что вы сами не знаете что именно вам нужно :)

Comment: вобщем паттерн я понимаю, как рассылку на несколько от сервера на несколько клиентов с помощью потоков тоже понимаю. Надо сделать расслку сообщений с помощью паттерна наблюдатель. но как передать в параметре запущенный сервер?

Comment: @Наташенька либо я не понял ваш вопрос, либо вы выбрали неверный подход. Зачем вам передавать запущенный сервер? Рассмотрим небольшой пример tcp сервера и вашу задачу(о5 такие если я ее верно понимаю) - клиент подключается к серверу, после этого клиент имеет некий объект serverConnection, а сервер clientSocket. Собственно ваша задача заключается в том, что-бы обвернуть первое и второе, вот и все. Что касается рассылки событий нескольким клиентам, опять таки - для этого мы держим коллекцию подключений, проходясь по которой и рассылаем. Если у вас остались вопросы - задавайте

Comment: рассылка почты это классический пример применения паттерна, интерфейс для клиента, класс с коллекцией и методами для подписки, отписки, оповещения клиентов для сервера.

Comment: по-другому спрошу))) как добавить клиент в коллекцию клиентов ранее созданного сервера. уточню сервер и клиент - это разные приложения. Они во всём могут взаимодействовать друг с другом. Только я не знаю, как сказать серверу "Я твой клиент. Добавь меня пожалуйста в свою коллекцию".

Comment: расхватали на цитаты, я твой клиент )

Comment: понятно...

Comment: server.registerObserver(this)?? Вы, когда подключаете клиента, как-бы, в случае успеха, должны регистрировать подписчика (т.е. на стороне сервера), не?

В общем - вы пытаетесь реализовать серверную логику на клиенте, не удивительно что у вас ничего не получается и вы, даже, толком не можете описать свою проблему :)

Comment: не удивительно? проблема не в этом. при создании клиента в конструкторе вызывается метод сервера, на сервере есть все обработчики. если писать всё в одном мейне, то всё работает. данная реализайия шаблона стопудово правильная. проблема в передаче параметра клиенту, если мейны разные. один объект сервера уже созлан и нельзя создать второй с таким же портом. @AlexWindHope, не умничайте, если не понимаете, идите в другую тему, если в этой ничего не понимаете.

Comment: давайте разберемся )) сервер - то кто ждет подключения, клиент - тот кто инициализирует подключение, правильно? запускаем сервер со своим мейн классом для прослушивания определенного порта, пусть будет на локалхолте, потом запускаем клиент на этой же машине для подключения к этому порту, правильно? на каком этапе чтото не получается? подлючились, обменялись информацией, закрыли порты, профит.

Comment: @Наташенька, если вы еще не поняли - я вам пытался (причем довольно настойчиво и деликатно) объяснить то, что вы не в ту сторону копаете и вообще толком не понимаете того, что делаете и того, что вам нужно.

"если не понимаете..." я вас, как раз таки - понял, это вы меня не в какую не хотите понимать, ну да ладно, мне действительно больше нечего делать в этой теме.

Во, я, кажется, понял, автор, судя по всему, пишет "клиент-серверное приложение" в котором клиент не только клиент, но и сервер :)

Comment: > для полного прикола добавлю код

вот уж действительно для прикола код по приколу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю [@Наташенька](/users/5963/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0) то дева пытается реализовать [паттерн Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) следующим макаром:

1. Есть сервак который держит список клиентов он же в терминах избранного паттерна является `Subject` - то есть тот который держит список `Observer`'ов
2. Есть клиенты они же `Observer`'ы, который получают некие сообщения/события от сервера/`subject`'а
3. Вопрос заключается в том, как серверу добавлять обсерверов в свой список

Ответ (в меру моего понимания) такой: очевидно после авторизации или какого-то процесса после которого сервер понимает, что клиент который стучится к нему это его клиент. Такой процесс называется [handshaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking).

А уж правила handshaking'а будьте добры разработайте сами! Например, в SSL handshake [выглядит так](http://www.pierobon.org/ssl/ch2/handstep.htm), а в TCP [выглядит так](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)